# ListView and BeginEdit method

Tags: c#, listviewitem

I have a ListView. When I call `listview.SelectedItems[0].BeginEdit()`, it is able to correct the selected item. What event needs to be called, when I end edit my item, for example, press such button as "Enter"?

At first, when the user selects ToolStripMenuItem it is occurs so event:

```
private void renameLocalUserToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView_ad.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        listView_ad.SelectedItems[0].BeginEdit();
    }
}
```

When the user ends changing his item, he presses "enter". And then I need to take the changed text.

Comment: The question is not very clear. Could you rephrase what you are asking and possible include the snippet of code you are having trouble with ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the 'AfterLabelEdit' event.

[MSDN AfterLabelEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.afterlabeledit%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y0)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear, but I think what you need is to handle the `AfterLabelEdit` event.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the [AfterLabelEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.listview.afterlabeledit%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) event.